# Display author with link (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display my latest 3 blog posts on my website homepage. I've got everything so far (Content, Image and Date). However it's not allowing me to display the authors name with link so that people can click on the author and see what their latest posts have been. Does anybody know why this is happening?

**My code so far:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<?php   
     $args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'offset' => 1, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
     $postslist = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>
<div class="blog-post blog-media wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="300ms" data-wow-delay="100ms">
   <article class="media clearfix">
      <div class="entry-thumbnail pull-left">
         <div class="img-responsive smallBlogImage"><?php getTheFirstImage(); ?></div>
             <span class="post-format post-format-gallery"><img class="blogIconSmall" src="IsosecWeb/images/IsosecIcon.png"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
         <header class="entry-header">
            <div class="entry-date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
         </header>

         <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(preg_replace("/\< *[img][^\>]*[.]*\>/i","", get_the_content(), 80), 20); ?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
         </div>

         <footer class="entry-meta">
             <span class="entry-author"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo the_author_posts_link(); ?> </span>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </article>
</div>
<?php  endforeach;  ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nope - with or without `echo` it still gives me nothing, is there anything wrong in my code that i'm not calling to get the information?

Comment: who had insert post?admin or user?

Comment: @vrajesh The admin has the insert post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

The reason why this is not showing up is because `the_author_posts_link();` needs to be used in [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and only the loop.

If you `print_r($postslist)` you will get an array back like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2015-07-03 11:04:24 [post_date_gmt] => 2015-07-03 11:04:24 [post_content] => Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging! [post_title] => Hello world! [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => hello-world [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2015-07-19 21:11:24 [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-07-19 21:11:24 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost:8888/intelligence/?p=1 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => post [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) )
```

What you need to do is access the key values individually. So for example, to get the date, if you would access it like so:

```
<?php echo postslist['post_date']; ?>
```

**The Author Link**

You will notice if you look at the `post_author` key, it returns an integer value, or the id of the admin. What we can do is then pass this into the

```
<span class="entry-author">
     <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
     <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $postslist['post_author'] ); ?>
</span>
```

You can access the authors link as so:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $postslist['post_author'] ); ?>">
    Posts by  <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $postslist['post_author'] ); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted, i've already got the post date, if you read my question. I only need the authors link. However this worked for me

Comment: Neither do I tbh. If it still doesn't work, post a gist and I will have a look for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: This will not work since `$postslist['post_author']`  will give you the *undefined index* notice.

Comment: If you `var_dump($postslist);` you will see that the index is there. The success of this depends what context you use this approach in, and it works in the OP's situation (+ tested).

Comment: Note that `get_posts()` returns array of `\WP_Post` objects, so you must use `$post->post_author` instead of `$postslist['post_author']` when OP loops over `$postslist`.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between `$post->post_author` and `$postslist['post_author']` when accessing the array in this context?

Comment: The `$postslists` is an array of `\WP_Post` objects so in the foreach iteration the `$post` becomes an `\WP_Post` object, so we use `$post->post_author`. If instead  `$postslists` would be an array of arrays (like the one from your print_r), then we would use `$post['post_data']`. In both these cases, `$postslist['post_author']` would be undefined, but  we should be able to use  `$postslist[$i]->post_author` or `$postslist[$i]['post_author']` where `$i` is the relevant position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name',$post->post_author); ?></a>
```

Comment: Could please explain your answer? but I don't know why this has been downvoted

Comment: This is the exact same as the approach mentioned. All that you are doing is accessing the array differently?

Comment: I used $post not $postslist ..and my function is also get_the_author_meta() not the_author_meta() @ham-sandwich

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty correct. The function "the_author_posts_link()" returns anchor tag - which links to all post by the author. There is no need to write "echo" to print it.

You just need to replace

```
<?php echo the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

with

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

and it will work.

Comment: No, it won't. You can only call `the_author_posts_link();` function within the WP loop